# Regex - Match certain patterns while excluding others?

Tags: python, regex, text-mining

I have text data that I want to clean (i.e. keep only alphanumeric characters) with Python. However, most of the text data I encounter contain emoji(s). I want to clean the text from non-alphanumerics, but **still keep the emoji**.

First, I used the `emoji` library in Python to convert each emoji in a text to a certain string pattern to make it distinguishable. An example of an emoji that has been "demojized" (a literal function in the library) is shown below:

```
':smiley_face:' # a "demojized" emoji.
```

After scrolling through the data, I find that these emojis (once "demojized") exhibit the same pattern, which in regex terms seems to be

```
':[a-z_]+:' # regex for matching emojis.
```

Ok, so I know the pattern for emojis and I can extract every emoji from the text data I have. The problem is, I want to clean the text data from non-alphanumerics **without altering the emoji pattern** simultaneously. My initial attempt to clean the data:

```
>>> text = 'Wow.. :smiley_face: this is delicious!' # A string containing emoji
>>> cleaned_text = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9]+',' ',text) # regex to keep only alphanumerics
>>> print(cleaned_text)
Wow smiley face this is delicious
```

Clearly this isn't my desired output. I want to keep the emoji text intact, as shown below:

```
'Wow :smiley_face: this is delicious' # Desired output
```

So far I have looked into things like lookahead assertion, but to no avail. Is it possible with regex to remove non-alphanumerics whilst excluding the `':[a-z_]+:'` pattern from the match? Apologies if question is unclear.

Comment: I understand the problem is that you cannot really easily tell a real textual emoji like `:smiley_face:` from `:ohIjustthoughtitup:`, right? Or do you just want to remove all special chars except the colons and `_` inside those `colon-word-colon` contexts? If the latter, just use `re.sub(r'(:[a-z_]+:)|[^\w\s]|_', r'\1', text)`, see [the Python demo](https://ideone.com/vQqzKX).

Comment: It’s the latter. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to remove all special chars except the colons and underscores inside  `colon-word(s)-colon` contexts, you can use

```py
re.sub(r'(:[a-z_]+:)|[^\w\s]|_', r'\1', text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ew8Izj/1). *Details*:

- `(:[a-z_]+:)`  - Capturing group 1 (`\1`): `:`, one or more lowercase ASCII letters or `_`, and a `:`
- `|` - or
- `[^\w\s]|_` - any char other than a word and whitespace char or a `_` (it is a word char, hence it needs to be added as an alternative).

See [the Python demo](https://ideone.com/vQqzKX):

```py
import re
text = 'Wow.. :smiley_face: this is delicious!' # A string containing emoji
print( re.sub(r'(:[a-z_]+:)|[^\w\s]|_', r'\1', text) )
# => Wow :smiley_face: this is delicious
```